# jQuery plugin waitForImages not waiting for images?

Tags: jquery, waitforimages

I am developing a plugin to do image blending with images.
You can see it at the following url: http://www.psfinteractive.it/bigoom/try.html
I call the plugin twice with two sets of images but the rendered image is the one that belongs to the second set.
Any ideas?

EDIT: Actually after correcting a typo, nothing is rendered now, help!

```
   return this.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $trioid = 't_'+uniqid();

  $trio = $('<div style="display:none" id="'+$trioid+'">');
  $('body').append($trio);

  $mask = $('<img id="mask"/>');
  $centre = $('<img id="centre"/>');
  $bg = $('<img id="bg"/>');

  $trio.append($mask);
  $trio.append($centre);
  $trio.append($bg);

  $mask.attr('src','');
  $centre.attr('src',settings.user);
  $bg.attr('src',settings.bckg);

  $('#'+$trioid).waitForImages({
      finished: function(){
        setupScene($this);
      }, waitForAll: true
      });

});
```

};

This is now working partially and only in Firefox, it seems that somehow new combinations are not read. Any ideas?
i have put some no cache headers via php and html in the file:

http://www.psfinteractive.it/bigoom/try.php

Comment: It's weird that there's no error thrown, but I noticed you are loading your own plugin before you are loading the `waitForImages` one. Since you are calling its method in your own plugin you should be loading it before you are loading your own?

Comment: Corrected it as per your suggestion, still no go.

Comment: Ummm, I just noticed a little typo btw: `waiForAll` should probably be `waitForAll`, right? Although I have no idea if that is the origin of your problem.

Comment: Hey m90 thanks for pointing that out.
I corrected the typo and now nothing works at all!

Comment: [It should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/QyN6r/).

Comment: actually, it only works in firefox and safari for some weird reason;
also, I have to refresh the page for it to work correctly

Comment: I have found an alternate solution which seems to work quite consistently on the html5 enabled browsers.

Comment: @amenegazzo Do you care to share it as an answer?